# Hyphenate \ttfamily without hyphen dash

Tags: hyphenation, typewriter

Is it possible to hyphenate text without inserting a hyphen.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{courier}
%\usepackage{bera}
%\usepackage{arev}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=\defaulthyphenchar\relax
LoremipsumdolorsitametconsectetueradipiscingelitAeneancommodo
ligulaegetdolorAeneanmassaCumsociisnatoquepenatibusetmagnisdis
parturientmontesnasceturridiculusmusDonecquamfelisultriciesnec
\end{document}
```

If I replace `\defaulthyphenchar` by `255` it works for CM, but not with Bera Mono. So is there a `\char` number of the word joiner (Unicode `U+2060`) that works with all fonts?

Comment: I only know how to define a hyphenation point manually that does not insert anything: `\def\+{\discretionary{}{}{}}`. Using `\+` gives you such a point but I don't know how to make this work for the automatically generated hyphenation points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no character in position 255 in Computer Modern Typewriter Type in OT1 encoding. If you add the line

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and replace `\defaulthyphenchar` with 255, you'll get `ß` as the "hyphen".

The package `bera` loads the font in T1 encoding, so you get `ß` as well.

If the font is OT1 encoded, any number between 128 and 255 (extremes included) will work, as there's no character there; if the font is T1 encoded, you can use (abuse, actually) the "compound word mark", which is in position 23.

Comment: Ahhh. I forgot the thing with the font encodings. Thank you!